# Constantly Open BLE Connection Between OS X and iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

I have been exploring CoreBluetooth and BLE connections between OS X and iOS, where I've discovered an interesting problem.  I have the Mac implementing CoreBluetooth central and iOS implementing CoreBluetooth peripheral.  Since iOS no longer broadcasts a constant, consistent MAC address or other identifier, there is no reliable way (that I can find) to allow the Mac to connect to the iOS peripheral whenever it is in range, including when the iOS app is running in the background.

By storing the last connected peripheral, I can get OS X to constantly search for the iOS device like shown:

```
[central connectPeripheral:self.lastPeripheral options:nil];
```

Which works if `self.lastPeripheral` was previously connected to the OS X client.  This initial connection can only be created if the iOS app is open at the time; it will not work if it is backgrounded.  This in itself is not a horrible issue, but every single time the OS X app quits, this connection must be reinstated by opening the iOS app.

Is there any way to connect and reconnect (when the device moves back into range) via BLE to an iOS device when the iOS application is backgrounded, especially to persist between app launches?

Comment: I believe that if you pair the devices you will get a consistent UUID for the iOS device

Comment: That does indeed appear to get a consistent UUID, but that doesn't solve the problem of connecting to iOS when the iOS app is backgrounded.

Answer (score 1):

BluetoothLE is still a energy consuming technology. And Apple goes into great lengths to limit its "active" usage on iOS, in situation they don't deem as correct (e.g. background). That said, there are no guaranties on for how long a iOS device in peripheral mode continues to advertise (pre-requirement for reconnection).

Did you think about switching the roles. Making the OS X machine the peripheral, and the iOS device the central? I know from experience that iOS behaves much nicer when acting as a central.

Comment: Yes.  Apple's bluetooth rules are often rather strict...    I had considered doing that, but it seemed that the power constraints would make it even more impractical (much better for a Mac to be constantly scanning vs the iOS device).  Will iOS will be able to quickly reconnect to the Mac after being out of range for a time?

Comment: Actually it's the opposite. BLE scanning is passive in nature, that is: only the peripheral is advertising (using TX power mode) what services it provides. The central part only listens (using RX power mode) and optionally can perform a additional active step. As a rule RX < TX when it comes to power.